# Как обернуть декоратор другим декоратором в typescript?

Tags: typescript

Есть такой код:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.usersRepository.find();
  }
}
```

Основная задача - обернуть репозиторий, что инжектится через `@InjectRepository(User)` в единую обертку над базой данных.

Вот обертка:

```
class Wrapper {
  private repository: any;

  constructor(repository: any) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  async find() {
    const result = await this.repository.find();
    return [result, 'Test'];
  }
}
```

Как ее подключить через декоратор?

Пытался так:

```
function testDecorator(a: any): any {
  return () => {
    const test = InjectRepository(a);
    return new UniversalRepository(test);
  };
}
```

Вызов его:

```
@(testDecorator(User)());
```

**Да только не работает это все** - `var decorated = decorator(target). TypeError: decorator is not a function`.

**Работает, только, если сделать так:**

```
 function work(a: any):any {
   return InjectRepository(a);
 }
```

**Но нужна обертка.** Как решить?

Comment: может быть тебе нужен custom repository? https://typeorm.io/#/custom-repository https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#custom-repository

Comment: Больше это: https://typeorm.io/#/entity-manager-api, так-как не очень хочется наследоваться для каждой сущности. Смотрел на него (entity-manager-api), только не смог его подключить через https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/typeorm. Там, в документации есть метод: https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/blob/cfa8b130d0dec5c3c47b822996124ef7b60180a7/lib/common/typeorm.decorators.ts, https://i.imgur.com/4PhwiV9.png, но что-то не вышло "заставить" его работать.